# Bank details for a custom stripe connect account

Tags: stripe-payments

When dealing with Stripe's custom connect accounts, do I need to enter the bank information manually using their API or is it possible to get the bank information as part of the onboarding process that Stripe offers for custom accounts?

I am using the following onboarding to allow Stripe to handle the entire verification process for my custom connect accounts:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/connect-onboarding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosted onboarding does not collect bank account details as part of the flow, by design(it only handles identity verification). This is information you'd need to collect from the user in your own onboarding forms and then pass to the API to create the payout destination via the ExternalAccount APIs https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_accounts

For example, as part of your onboarding flow, you might build a page that collects some basic information from the user like their email address, uses [stripe.js to collect bank account details](https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=bank_account), and then submit to your server to create the Account object and then send the user through the hosted identity verification flow.

Comment: That makes sense, does Stripe provide a way to know what fields are required for the bank details depending on the country the user is in?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of no. In most countries you just collect a routing and account number and pass to `routing_number` and `account_number`, in Europe you collect a single IBAN and pass as `account_number`. You'd test this in test mode using the [values for the countries you're interested](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#account-numbers) in before launching there.